# Erro ao atualizar Cordova

Tags: node.js, apache-cordova, ionic

Ao tentar atualizar o Cordova em meu computador o Node está gerando o seguinte erro.

```
    D:\Desenv\tfs-soek\xampp\biltspot>npm install -g cordova
    npm ERR! Error: connect EACCES
    npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)
    npm ERR!  { [Error: connect EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES',         syscall: 'c
    onnect' }
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
    npm ERR! cwd D:\Desenv\tfs-soek\xampp\biltspot
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.39
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
    npm ERR! syscall connect
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno EACCES
    npm ERR! stack Error: connect EACCES
    npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     D:\Desenv\tfs-soek\xampp\biltspot\npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Já tentei desisntalar e reinstalar, rodar como Administrador, upgrade e downgrade de versão.

O erro começou a ocorrer quando atualizei o Node em meu PC para a versão mais nova.

Obs, nem instalar plugins não está instalando no momento

Se alguém tiver uma ideia e puder me ajudar estou aberto

Um grande abraço

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, no meu computador tenho Norton 360 e ele administra o Firewall do sistema. Não sei por qual motivo o Norton não estava iniciando e o Node não conseguia passar pelo Firewall, iniciei o Norton e ele voltou a funcionar

Comment: seria interessante postar isso como resposta se você resolveu!

Comment: @gustavohenke já está no comentário acima. Essa foi a solução para o problema